# Tuple struct to function coercion : what are the lifetime parameters of said function?

Tags: rust

I don't understand something about the feature that makes it possible to coerce a tuple struct to a function as in:

```rust
struct MyType(u8);

let optional_mytype: Option<MyType> = Some(12).map(MyType);
//                                                 ^^^^^^ here, MyType is treated as a function
```

In the example above, no lifetimes are involved: everything is easy. However, when the structure has a generic lifetime bound, I'm having troubles defining the exact signature of the function it would coerce to.

Here's a MRE of something I've attempted to do, and that doesn't work ([sandbox link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bf4b17c915b6dea14b95cde3c33ad52)):

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a>(&'a ());

// This looks, to me, like the signature the "constructor" should have
type MyStructConstructor = for<'a> fn(&'a ()) -> MyStruct<'a>;

/// Coercion problem here
fn some_code() {
    let mut constructor: MyStructConstructor = MyStruct;
}
```

and the error given by the type-checker:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:7:48
  |
7 |     let mut constructor: MyStructConstructor = MyStruct;
  |                                                ^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
  |
  = note: expected fn pointer `for<'a> fn(&'a ()) -> MyStruct<'a>`
             found fn pointer `fn(&()) -> MyStruct<'_>`
```

And I honestly don't understand why my constructor type alias isn't valid, and why the type suggested by the error message is much more lax than it should be. I mean, the lifetime `<'a>` of my structure should be exactly equal to that of the unit reference that is contained by the structure, not a random one.

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bf4b17c915b6dea14b95cde3c33ad52)'s a more concrete (still minimal) example of what I'm actually trying to do, if having context helps you.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the error message might be a bit misleading. `'_` does not mean *any* lifetime goes, it just means *a lifetime I haven't named explicitly*, just as writing `&()` (which is the same as `&'_ ()`). Rust does that because that's not the issue.

To understand, let's actually annotate implicit generic lifetimes in your code:

```rust
fn some_code() {
  let constructor: MyStructConstructor = MyStruct<'_>;
}
```

Notice how something is wrong? On the right hand side, you have something whose type is generic over a lifetime. On the left hand side, you don't.
In fact, a more appropriate constructor signature for `MyStruct` would be

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a>(&'a ());

type MyStructConstructor<'a> = fn(&'a ()) -> MyStruct<'a>;

fn some_code() {
  let constructor: MyStructConstructor = MyStruct;
}
```

leaving the lifetime implicit — see [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f2b981637585794a7cf85b7c0d2cf20).
This compiles.

So now you may understand why `MyStructConstructor` was more generic than `MyStruct`: because for `MyStruct`, you have to specify a lifetime to begin with, that is, the actual type is, for a given `'a`, `MyStruct<'a>`. Then, with that constructor, you are only capable of building objects of type `MyStruct<'a>`, given `&'a ()`. On the other hand, with `MyStructConstructor`, given a reference to a `()` with *any* lifetime, you would be able to build a `MyStruct` of the same lifetime, which is more general.

Comment: Thank you, I completely understand the issue now! I indeed didn't think about the elided lifetime of `MyStruct<'_>`.